# Slim templates on Ruby on Rails, what are best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, slim-lang

I have trouble understanding basic Slim syntax.

First question, how to do you enter new line (line break)?

Second request, could you please rewrite the following snippet, I suspect I didn't do it easy way?

```
- provide(:title, @course.title)                                                                                                          

.row
  aside.span4
    section
      h1 = @course.title.capitalize

      => link_to t('ui.edit'), edit_course_path(@course)
      '|
      => link_to t('ui.back'), courses_path

      p
        b #{t('activerecord.attributes.subject.title')}:
        | #{@course.subject.title}

      p
        b #{t('activerecord.attributes.student_level.title')}:
        | #{@course.student_level.title}

      h4 #{t('activerecord.attributes.course.objectives')}
      = @course.objectives
```

This is its output:

## Title a

tahrirlash (edit) | orqaga

**Predmet nomi:** english 5-7 year olds

**O'quvchi darajasi:** beginner

### Kurs haqida ma'lumot

objectives b

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For new line, you should just use br like:

```
h1 Line1 content
br
h1 Line2 content
```

And about the above mentioned code, it can be rewrite like this:

```
-provide(:title,@course.title)                                                    
.row
  aside.span4
    section
      h1 = @course.title.capitalize

      = link_to t('ui.edit'), edit_course_path(@course)
      '|
      = link_to t('ui.back'), courses_path

      p
        b = t('activerecord.attributes.subject.title')
        |:&nbsp;    
        = @course.subject.title

      p
        b = t('activerecord.attributes.student_level.title')
        |:&nbsp;
        = @course.student_level.title

      h4 = t('activerecord.attributes.course.objectives')
      = @course.objectives
```

Comment: Slim appears to not support single line <br> tags without breaking to new elements. The above example from Aman Garg forces a new <h1> tag. Alt: would be to do something like ```h1 content<br> content``` if you want it on the same line.

Comment: Downvoted because `$/` is significantly better. See my answer for reasons.

Answer (score 5):

To insert **br** tag into some tag in slim:

**Example 1.** Slim template:

```
h1
  | Hello
  br
  | world
```

It will produce html:

```
<h1>Hello<br>world</h1>
```

**Example 2.** Fragment of slim template for displaying form:

```
p
  = f.label :title
  br
  = f.text_field :title
```

It will produce html:

```
<p>
  <label for="question_title">Title</label><br>
  <input name="question[title]" id="question_title" type="text">
</p>
```